# Visual Studio 2015 RC C# Intellisense - some settings missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm looking for the specific checkbox listed on this Microsoft help article, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), where, under the C# -> IntelliSense tab, you can check if you want the space bar to auto complete, which I do not want it to do.

Can anyone help a Visual Studio novice find the setting? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like that article only applies to VS 2010 and below, pull down the "Other Versions" link.

Comment: Agree with @JohnKoerner. You can always try typing what you want into the Quick launch box in the top right corner.